# How to interact with a running python script

Tags: python-2.6, interactive

As a start ive got a basic script which reads local unix syslog (/var/log/messages)

i want to build a tool which opens a socket (19999) locally and allows admin commands to be sent / processed.

As something i can build on basically i want to have the script on start up do the follow : 
 - open port 19999 locally 
 - start reading syslog storing "line" as the last line it has processed. 
 - when admin command of "printline" is seen print last known variable for "line"

Ive got basics done i think (script is below) where i have it open the relevant ports and it prints the commands sent to it from another client tool however it never starts to read the syslog.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import subprocess
import sys
import time
from threading import Thread


MAX_LENGTH = 4096

def handle(clientsocket):
 while 1:
   buf = clientsocket.recv(MAX_LENGTH)
   if buf == '': return #client terminated connection
   print buf

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

PORT = 19999
HOST = '127.0.0.1'

serversocket.bind((HOST, PORT))
serversocket.listen(10)

while 1:
    #accept connections from outside
   (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()

ct = Thread(target=handle, args=(clientsocket,))
ct.start()


def follow(thefile):
thefile.seek(0,2)
while True:
    line = thefile.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        continue
    yield line

if __name__ == '__main__':
 logfile = open("/capture/log/uifitz/messages","r")
 loglines = follow(logfile)
 for line in loglines:
    print line,
```

Any help would be appreciated. Python 2.6 by the way.